# Why can I not place Master and Detail view next to each other in UISplitViewController on the first run, but upon rotation it works?

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, swift2, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a split view controller that has a list of items on the left and a detail view on the right. Relevant code in AppDelegate:

```
let splitViewController = mainView.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("initial") as! UISplitViewController



        let rightNavController = splitViewController.viewControllers.last as! UINavigationController
        let detailViewController = rightNavController.topViewController as! DetailsIpad

        let leftNavController = splitViewController.viewControllers.first as! UINavigationController
        let masterViewController = leftNavController.topViewController as! MainViewController

        masterSplitViewController = masterViewController
        detailSplitViewController = detailViewController

        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        let navigationController = splitViewController.viewControllers[splitViewController.viewControllers.count-1] as! UINavigationController
        navigationController.topViewController!.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = splitViewController.displayModeButtonItem()
        splitViewController.delegate = self

        self.window!.rootViewController = splitViewController
```

When I first launch the app I see that the right part of the split screen takes up all of the screen:

[image]

If I rotate the screen, it becomes properly set (probably because both views are present on the screen):

[image]

When I set breakpoints everywhere, I see that the detail view on the right gets loaded before the master view on the left (list of items), despite not being called directly. 
I cannot change the order in which the views of the split screen are called. How can I fix this?

**UPDATE:**

I am able to set this before showing split view controller:

```
splitViewController.preferredDisplayMode = UISplitViewControllerDisplayMode.AllVisible
```

And in the ViewDidLoad of the split controller when I am printing it:

```
print(self.preferredDisplayMode.rawValue)
```

I get: 2, which is AllVisible. But still result is the same.

Comment: I'm not sure the issue is the order the views are loading.  This is the default behavior of a splitView controller in landscape/portrait mode.  Are you wanting the detail view to be next to the master view in portrait mode?

Comment: @DJohnson yes, I want it to be next to the master, like in the second picture..

Comment: the problem is that it IS like on the second picture ONLY after rotation, but on initial run, it's like on the first picture..

Comment: @DJohnson actually, sorry, no, only in landscape mode I want it to be like this (portrait mode is not activated)

Comment: Did you try `-setNeedsUpdateConstraints` after loading the second view?

Comment: yes, I tried this as well.. didn't work

Comment: Have you tried setting the view controllers by array? Like `splitViewController.viewControllers = [master, detail]`

Comment: Setting frame(CGRect) sometimes creates this problem try NSLayoutConstraint for the views

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Tarun Tyagi for the explanation, but in my case the suggested actions did not work. However, this worked for me: in the SplitViewController I added a call for setNeedsLayout():

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.view.setNeedsLayout()
}
```

That will make the view refresh when the view is on screen already.

Answer (score 4):

It's the default behavior of `UISplitViewController`. Have a close look at the following-

```
// An animatable property that controls how the primary view controller is hidden and displayed. A value of `UISplitViewControllerDisplayModeAutomatic` specifies the default behavior split view controller, which on an iPad, corresponds to an overlay mode in portrait and a side-by-side mode in landscape.
@property (nonatomic) UISplitViewControllerDisplayMode preferredDisplayMode NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);
```

Here's the key part from same definition-

> on an iPad, corresponds to an overlay mode in portrait and a side-by-side mode in landscape.

Also, if you want to query the current state (display mode) of a `UISplitViewController` you should use this property-

```
// The actual current displayMode of the split view controller. This will never return `UISplitViewControllerDisplayModeAutomatic`.
@property (nonatomic, readonly) UISplitViewControllerDisplayMode displayMode NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);
```

And remember, you can't compare this with `UISplitViewControllerDisplayModeAutomatic` because-

> This will never return `UISplitViewControllerDisplayModeAutomatic`.

My suggestion would be to set `preferredDisplayMode` to the value you want. In your case, it seems like you need the primary (master) to always be visible. So here's the proposed solution-

```
mySplitVC.preferredDisplayMode = UISplitViewControllerDisplayModeAllVisible
```

#### Why it loads the secondary(detail) controller first?

As you can see, a `UISplitViewController` instance always needs a detail view no matter what `displayMode` it is in currently. So it's a good call to

- load the detail view first.
- load the primary view after (conditionally based on displayMode).

Hope this helps.

Comment: this is the problem: I have this setting already on self.preferredDisplayMode = UISplitViewControllerDisplayMode.AllVisible , and tried all other things - did not help me

Comment: I have been left out with the only option: re-do the whole tutorial from scratch, because nothing seems to work